# Insert data from python Dataframe to Hive

Tags: python-2.7

I am able to read data from hive to python using Pyhive library but unable to write data from Pandas Dataframe to Hive. Cannot use pyspark for this.
Please let me know alternative solutions for this.

Comment: Raghav Mehta, if you ask general questions without supplementing them with proper code or particular links, you will only end up encouraging people to downvote your question. Please supply the appropriate code or the error messages, if any, to demonstrate the problem at hand. Once problem has been clearly marked, there will be many to help you.

Comment: thanks cph_sto i will surely make note of this.